# find Equator from coordination data in mysql table

Tags: mysql

i have a table for some coordination data.
like this:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+
| fdid |  rtime      | lat         |
+------+-------------+-------------+
|    1 |  1589673600 | -40.1458523 |
|    2 |  1589673601 | -40.1458523 |
|    3 |  1589673602 | -40.1458523 |
|    4 |  1589673603 | -39.8598215 |
|    5 |  1589673604 | -39.8598215 |
|    6 |  1589673605 | -39.8598215 |
|    7 |  1589673606 | -39.8598215 |
|    8 |  1589673607 | -39.8598215 |
|    9 |  1589673608 | -39.8598215 |
|   10 |  1589673609 | -39.8598215 |
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

there are fields with name lat, representing Latitude

also the rtime is a timestamp.

these data are a vehicle on earth , now i have find when the vehicle go over / or pass the Equator 
my query is like this

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROUND(rtime/1000,0) grtime,
    count(*) acount,
    min(rtime) mitime,
    max(rtime) matime 
FROM `fds_data` 
WHERE `lat`<0.5 and lat>-0.5 
GROUP BY grtime;
```

but i thing this is not a complete solution.is there any way for better result !?

Comment: Luckily, this never happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case consistent data (data record each second) you can find Equator pass by next simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` `t1`
JOIN `table` `t2` ON `t2`.`rtime`  = (`t1`.`rtime` + 1) -- join next record
WHERE `t1`.`lat` * `t2`.`lat` <= 0; -- check Equator pass
```